# Add element to array conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two array

```
var arr1 = ["xxx", "yyy"]

var arr2 = [
 {domain="xxx", kwd="a", position=1},
 {domain="yyy", kwd="a", position=2},

 {domain="xxx", kwd="b", position=1},
 {domain="yyy", kwd="b", position=2},

 {domain="yyy", kwd="c", position=2},

 {domain="xxx", kwd="d", position=1}

 ]
```

I want that when for a **domain** in arr1 there isn't a **kdw** in arr2 for that domain, will be push `position="n/a"`. So based of the arrays above the output should be:

```
var arr3 = [
 {domain="xxx", kwd="a", position=1},
 {domain="yyy", kwd="a", position=2},

 {domain="xxx", kwd="b", position=1},
 {domain="yyy", kwd="b", position=2},

 {domain="xxx", kwd="c", position="n/a"},
 {domain="yyy", kwd="c", position=2},

 {domain="xxx", kwd="d", position=1},
 {domain="yyy", kwd="d", position="n/a"},
    
]
```

I have no idea on how to achieve that.
I have started this piece of code but I don't know if it is relevant or not:

```
var arr1 = [domain="xxx", domain="yyy" ]
        
var arr2 = [{domain="xxx", kwd="a", position=1},{domain="yyy", kwd="a", position=2}, {domain="xxx", kwd="b", position=1}, {domain="yyy", kwd="b", position=2},{domain="yyy", kwd="c", position=2}, {domain="xxx", kwd="d", position=1}]   
    
    var arr3 [];
        
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < arr2.domain.length; i++) { 
        if(// logic  ) {
            arr3.push({
            domain: arr2[i].domain,
            kwd: arr2[i].kwd,
            position: arr2[i].position
          }) else {
            arr3.push({
            domain: arr2[i].domain,
            kwd: arr2[i].domain,
            position: "n/a"
          }
        }
   }
```

}

Thanks in advance for any help. Kind regards.

Comment: one question, how doesn't `arr2` and `arr3` produce an error?

Comment: Are all the domain values actually unique?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes.

Comment: Then provide samples with unique values and expected results. Hard to figure it out when you made them all the same. See [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr1 = ["xxx", "yyy"];

var arr2 = [
  { domain: "xxx", kwd: "a", position: 1 },
  { domain: "yyy", kwd: "a", position: 2 },

  { domain: "xxx", kwd: "b", position: 1 },
  { domain: "yyy", kwd: "b", position: 2 },

  { domain: "yyy", kwd: "c", position: 2 },

  { domain: "xxx", kwd: "d", position: 1 }
];

const grouped = arr2.reduce((group, entry) => {
  const lookup = group[entry.kwd] || {};
  return {
    ...group,
    [entry.kwd]: {
      ...lookup,
      [entry.domain]: entry
    }
  };
}, {});

const filledIn = Object.entries(grouped).reduce(
  (arr, [key, group]) => [
    ...arr,
    ...arr1.map((domain) =>
      domain in group
        ? group[domain]
        : {
            domain,
            kwd: key,
            position: "n/a"
          }
    )
  ],
  []
);

console.log(filledIn);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to edit a bit your script but I got an issue. If you please could have a look [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437383/javascrpt-array-group-return-undefined-key-value).